# How can I run Gulp tasks only after all of the default items pass with no error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

What I would like to do is only run the console.log if all three of the tasks complete successfully. Currently, the js lint item is the only item that seems to have built in functionality to break out if there is an error.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var csslint = require('gulp-csslint');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var htmlhint = require('gulp-htmlhint');

gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'css', 'html'], function() {
  console.log('hi');
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src('*.css')
    .pipe(csslint())
    .pipe(csslint.reporter());
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.result(function(result) {
      console.log('ESLint result: ' + result.filePath);
      console.log('# Messages: ' + result.messages.length);
      console.log('# Warnings: ' + result.warningCount);
      console.log('# Errors: ' + result.errorCount);
    }))
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(htmlhint())
    .pipe(htmlhint.reporter());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `fail` to the CSS linter's reporter call, `.pipe(csslint.reporter('fail'));` and use the HTML linter's failReport `htmlhint.failReporter()` vs `.pipe(htmlhint.reporter());`.

So in full:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var csslint = require('gulp-csslint');
var eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
var htmlhint = require('gulp-htmlhint');

gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'css', 'html'], function() {
  console.log('hi');
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src('*.css')
    .pipe(csslint())
    .pipe(csslint.reporter('fail'));
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
  return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(eslint.format())
    .pipe(eslint.result(function(result) {
      console.log('ESLint result: ' + result.filePath);
      console.log('# Messages: ' + result.messages.length);
      console.log('# Warnings: ' + result.warningCount);
      console.log('# Errors: ' + result.errorCount);
    }))
    .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(htmlhint())
    .pipe(htmlhint.failReporter());
});
```